# Python module getting too big

Tags: python, python-module

My module is all in one big file that is getting hard to maintain.  What is the standard way of breaking things up?

I have one module in a file `my_module.py`, which I import like this:

```
import my_module
```

"my_module" will soon be a thousand lines, which is pushing the limits of my ability to keep everything straight.  I was thinking of adding files `my_module_base.py`, `my_module_blah.py`, etc.  And then, replacing `my_module.py` with

```
from my_module_base import *
from my_module_blah import *
# etc.
```

Then, the user code does not need to change:

```
import my_module  # still works...
```

Is this the standard pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what your module is doing actually. Usually it is always a good idea to make your module a directory with an '`__init__.py'` file inside. So you would first transform your `your_module.py` to something like `your_module/__init__.py`.

After that you continue according to your business logic. Here some examples:

- do you have utility functions which are not directly used by the modules API put them in some file called `utils.py`
- do you have some classes dealing with the database or representing your database models put them in `models.py`
- do you have some internal configuration it might make sense to put it into some extra file called `settings.py` or `config.py`

These are just examples (a little bit stolen from the Django approach of reusable apps ^^). As said, it depends a lot what your module does. If it is still too big afterwards it also makes sense to create submodules (as subdirectories with their own `__init__.py`).

Comment: When someone imports my module, what happens besides the `__init__.py` being sourced?  If nothing, would I put statements like `from blah import *` in my `__init__.py`?

Comment: You can do this, BUT as stated here already it is not good practice. See Senthil Kumaran's answer below about how it would be better to do. Import just what you module should offer to the outside when doing `import my_module`. Everything else should be "hidden" inside the modules logic.

Answer (score 2):

i'm sure there are lots of opinions on this, but I'd say you break it into more well-defined functional units (modules), contained in a package. Then you use:

```
from mypackage import modulex
```

Then use the package name to reference the object:

```
modulex.MyClass()
```

etc.

You should (almost) never use

```
from mypackage import *
```

Since that can introduce bugs (duplicate names from different modules will end up clobbering one).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I wasn't sure that my question was well-worded.  Please see my recent edits.

Comment: Ok, sure. But does the user need everything? Sometime for transitioning you can provide an extra, backwards compatibility module that pulls everything in. That's the "almost" exception. ;-)

Comment: While it may not always be appropriate, you can also use the form `from mypackage import modulex as mx` or some other shorter name.

Comment: You can also import frequently-used named explicitly, by adding(!) `from mypackage.modulex import MyClass` etc. - little to no name clash risk as you see all the names imported at a glance, but makes things much more convenient for users.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not the standard pattern. `from something import *` is usually not a good practice as it will import lot of things you did not intend to. Instead follow the same approach as you did, but include the modules specifically from one to another for e.g.

In `base.py` if you are having `def myfunc` then in `main.py` use `from base import myfunc` So that for your users, `main.myfunc` would work too. Of course, you need to take care that you don't end up doing a circular import.

Also, if you see that `from something import *` is required, then control the import values using the `__all__` construct.